# Making Python Executable From Command Line

Tags: python, command-line, executable

So I have a project and our professor said to make sure our code can be intialized on a command line interface. How do I do that? And how do I test that I did it correct?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: i'm using windows @KlausD.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is start python and tell it to run your script. For example:

```
C:\Users\jhooper\Documents> py myprogram.py
```

Comment: but if I have method definition how does the user input them from the command line if they do that?

Comment: Python runs the top-level (i.e., not inside a class or function) code in the .py file. This usually contains code that asks the user for information that's needed to run the script.

Comment: The user shouldn't be defining methods. If your program has `input`, the user will be able to enter input in the command line. Have you tried running your program in the suggested manner?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yeah I just tried it and I got back D:\Documents\Google Drive\Coding\Python\Calc3Project> py ConvCodes.py
'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Joseph hooper: Use `python`, not `py`.  Also, use `input` for Python 3, `raw_input` for Python 2, for command-line data input.

Comment: You have to use whatever command you use to start Python. How do you get to the interactive interpreter? Add a space and then your filename to that command.